# node - Test multiple time form submission with puppeteer cli script

Tags: node.js, forms, automated-tests, puppeteer

I need to test some forms using puppeter. I want to do multiple attempt but I don't want to restart everytime the cli script I'm writing. Is possible with puppeteer to do the same task multiple time with a delay between each form submission test?

```js
(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    //executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome' 
    //args: ['--incognito']
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  
  page.goto('mysite.com/form').then( () => { ... })

  await browser.close();

})();
```

At the moment I have only this basic code. Starting from it I want to do the multiple test. I have the forms on two different urls and I want to do ten attempt to fill it. Any help or suggestion about how to proceed?